# How to retrieve superclass (subClassOf) identifiers (not labels) from OBO ontology using ROBOT?

Tags: ontology

I am currently running the ROBOT snippet

```
robot export --input data/cl.owl \
  --header "ID|LABEL|IAO_0000115|hasDbXref|subClassOf" \
  --export results/cl.csv
```

To retrieve entries from the Cell Ontology. Currently it retrieves something like:

```
CL:0000036,epithelial fate stem cell,,,single fate stem cell
```

Where "single fate stem cell" is the parent. Is there any way to retrieve the CL identifier instead of the label?

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation on rendering cell values in the ROBOT documentation:

http://robot.obolibrary.org/export.html#rendering-cell-values

Specifically, you can affix  `[ID]` onto the column descriptor, i.e. `SubClass Of [ID]`

So the command would look like this:

```
robot export --input data/cl.owl \
  --header "ID|LABEL|IAO_0000115|hasDbXref|subClassOf [ID]" \
  --export results/cl.csv
```

Which will give the desired result.